# Obter variavel declarada na função fora do decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tentei com o módulo `inspect` mas não consegui obter o resultado.
***O conceito é: "scaniar" um arquivo atráves de um `decorator`.***

#### Etapas

1. Capturar variável `file` antes da função `read_file` ser chamada
2. *"Scaniar"* arquivo
3. Devolver ou não a função que chamou o `decorator`

Tentei de varias formas e concordo que não achei nenhuma forma de fazer isso, até mesmo usando o módulo `inspect` da biblioteca Standard Python.

```
def scan_files(funcs):
    print(funcs.__code__.co_varnames)
    return funcs

@scan_files
def read_file():
    file = open('arquivo.txt', 'w')
    file.close()
    with open('arquivo.txt', 'w') as new_file: ...
```

*PS: por motivos de legibilidade omitir alguns fatores, como, funções com argumentos nomeados ou não, variável não ter o nome fixo sendo necessário saber o tipo tido como object file.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em Python, explícito é melhor que implícito. Da maneira que está fazendo você estaria ocultando regras dentro do decorador e isso afetaria a legibilidade do código. Até porque ter uma função que lê apenas um arquivo não parece fazer muito sentido; melhor seria se passasse o nome do arquivo por parâmetro.

```
def scanner(function):
    def wrapper(filename):
        print(f"Escaneando o arquivo {filename}")
        ...
        devolver = True  # Define se a função deverá ser executada ou não
        if devolver:
            return function(filename)
        return None
    return wrapper

@scanner
def read_file(filename):
    print(f"Abrindo o arquivo {filename}")
    with open(filename, 'w') as stream:
        ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    read_file('arquivo.txt')
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/BronzeMerryZenaida)</sup>

Assim, a saída seria algo como:

```
Escaneando o arquivo arquivo.txt
Abrindo o arquivo arquivo.txt
```

Pois o objeto `devolver`, que no seu caso será a condição de define se a função será executada ou não, está definido como `True`, fazendo com que a função execute normalmente. Se defini-lo para `False`, a saída será:

```
Escaneando o arquivo arquivo.txt
```

Não executando a função.

Comment: Não era bem isso o que eu pensei em desenvolver. A função que montei em si read_file, foi só um exemplo, mas pensei em algo maior como, uma função com manipulação com muitos arquivos. Porém, você me fez pensar em varias coisas, como legibilidade, usabilidade, manutenção, e omissão/geração de erros que isso com certeza irá acontecer. De certa forma você me ajudou indiretamente, então tenho só tenho a agradecer. Obrigado!